# sharepoint 2013 people search - custom facets

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I added a new custom property to my user properties store (Intranet Department).  It is attached to a term set.  For my profiles, I have selected one of the terms for the custom property I created.

I also have a search page with a search box, search results, and refinement web part on it.  My search results is set to query people.  In my refinement web part, I can see my custom property, but when I do my query, the refinement does not show up in refinement web part:

[image: Refinement selection]

[image: Results]

So what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Anyone have people search working with custom user properties as facets?

Answer (score 0):

I did not work on SharePoint 2013, I am working on SharePoint 2010.  I had similar issue in 2010, i resolved the issue by setting the Custom user property security setting VISIBILITY to "Everyone".  After that run the full indexing on the profiles.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  So my particular issue ended up being an index reset and full crawl.  I'm not sure why this is the case.  Thanks for the insight.